# PHP Contact Form Fixing

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have a PHP Contact form that was working correctly, but i made some changes to the some variables and it stopped working.

This is the PHP code below:

```
<?php

$action = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $position = $_POST['position'];
    $school = $_POST['school'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $zip = $_POST['zip'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $model = $_POST['model'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

$to = 'jasmeet0921@gmail.com';
$subject = '30 Day Evaluation Request -'.$name;
$body = 'Name: ' . $name .  "\n" .  
'Title/Position: ' . $position .  "\n" . 
'School: ' . $school .  "\n" .
'Address: ' . $address .  "\n" .  
'City: '. $city .  "\n" . 
'State: ' . $state .  "\n" . 
'Zip Code: ' . $zip .  "\n" . 
'Email: ' . $email .  "\n" .
'Phone Number: '. $phone .  "\n" . 
'Model To Evaluate: ' . $model .  "\n" . 
'Comments: ' . $comments .  "\n" . 

$headers = 'From: Sales <seorick1904@gmail.com>';
$thankyou = "thankyou.html"; // thank you page
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['school']) && isset($_POST['address']) && isset($_POST['city']) && isset($_POST['state']) && isset($_POST['zip']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone'])&& isset($_POST['model'])&& isset($_POST['comments']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $position = $_POST['position'];
    $school = $_POST['school'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $zip = $_POST['zip'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $model = $_POST['model'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

    if(empty($phone) || empty($comments) || empty($name) || empty($position) || empty($school) || empty($address) || empty($city) || empty($state) || empty($zip) || empty($email) || empty($model)){
        echo 'Fields With * Sign Are Mandatory';
    }
    else{
        if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)){
            echo "<div class='message'>" . $a = 'Your message has been successfully sent!' . "</div>";
            $name = "";
            $position = "";
            $school = "";
            $address = "";
            $city = "";
            $state = "";
            $zip = "";
            $email = "";
            $phone = "";
            $model = "";
            $comments = "";
        }
        else{
            echo 'There was an error sending email/s.';
        }
    }

}


?>
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="label">
                            Full Name:*
                        </div><!--Label-->

                        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" autocomplete="on" class="textbox" />
                    </div><!--Row-->

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="label">
                            Title/Position:
                        </div><!--Label-->
                        <input type="text" name="position" value="<?php echo $position; ?>" class="textbox" />
                    </div><!--Row-->

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="label">
                            School/District:*
                        </div><!--Label-->
                        <input type="text" name="school" value="<?php echo $school; ?>" class="textbox" />
                    </div><!--Row-->

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="label">
                            Address:*
                        </div><!--Label-->
                        <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $address; ?>" class="textbox" />
                    </div><!--Row-->

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="label">
                            City:*
                        </div><!--Label-->
                        <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $city; ?>" class="textbox" />
                    </div><!--Row-->

                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="label">
                            State:*
                        </div><!--Label-->
                    <select name="state" id="type" onchange="findselected()" class="listbox">
                        <option value="" <?php if($state === "") {echo "selected";} ?>>--Select--</option>

    <option  <?php if($state === "Alabama") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Alabama" >Alabama</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Alaska") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Alaska" >Alaska</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Arizona") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Arizona" >Arizona</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Arkansas") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Arkansas" >Arkansas</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "California") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="California" >California</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Colorado") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Colorado" >Colorado</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Connecticut") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Connecticut" >Connecticut</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Delaware") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Delaware" >Delaware</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Florida") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Florida" >Florida</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Georgia") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Georgia" >Georgia</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Hawaii") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Idaho") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Illinois") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Iowa") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Indiana") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Kansas") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Kentucky") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Iowa") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Louisiana") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Maine") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Maine">Maine</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Maryland") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Massachusetts") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Michigan") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Minnesota") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Mississippi") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Missouri") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Montana") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Montana">Montana</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Nebraska") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Nevada") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "New Hampshire") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "New Jersey") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "New Mexico") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "New York") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="New York">New York</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "North Carolina") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "North Dakota") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Ohio") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Oklahoma") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Oregon") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Pennsylvania") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Rhode Island") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "South Carolina") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "South Dakota") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Tennessee") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Texas") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Texas">Texas</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Utah") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Utah">Utah</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Vermont") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Virginia") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Washington") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Washington">Washington</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "West Virginia") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Wisconsin") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
    <option  <?php if($state === "Wyoming") {echo "selected";} ?>  value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
                    </select>
                    </div><!--Row-->

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="label">
                            Zip Code:*
                        </div><!--Label--> 
                        <input type="text" name="zip" value="<?php echo $zip; ?>" class="textbox" />
                    </div><!--Row-->

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="label">
                            Your Email:*
                        </div><!--Label-->
                        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" class="textbox" />
                    </div><!--Row-->

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="label">
                            Phone:*
                        </div><!--Label-->
                        <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" class="textbox" />
                    </div><!--Row-->

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="label">
                            Model To Evaluate:*
                        </div>
                        <!--Label-->
                        <select name="model" id="type" onchange="findselected()" class="listbox">
    <option <?php if($model === "") {echo "selected";} ?> value="" >--Select--</option>
    <option <?php if($model === "Solo 8") {echo "selected";} ?> value="Solo 8">Solo 8</option>
    <option <?php if($model === "Ne 3") {echo "selected";} ?> value="Ne 3">Ne 3</option>
    <option <?php if($model === "Mini 5") {echo "selected";} ?> value="Mini 5">Mini 5</option>
    </select>
                    </div><!--Row-->

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="label">
                            Comments:*
                        </div>
                        <!--Label-->

                         <textarea name="comments" class="textarea" style="overflow:hidden;" rows="" cols="" ><?php echo $comments; ?></textarea>
                    </div><!--Row-->

                    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="" />
                    <p><?php echo $a ?></p>
                    </form>
```

Whenever i click on submit i get "There is some error /s sending email".

The last `else` runs that is in the PHP code.

All fields are mandatory.

Comment: so undoo the changes

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: seriously its a basic debugging approach; go back to a working version, make one change at a time, testing after each, until you have found the change that breaks the code. Its easy to debug one line, hard to debug a whole script at once

Comment: @Dagon I had undo the changes but still didn't worked :(

Comment: Fix the end of your $body, its not ending ;

Answer (score 1):

One problem I can see:

```
'Comments: ' . $comments .  "\n" .
```

The old missing semicolon.

Comment: I had made this change but still it didn;t worked :(.... is there anything else we ca try?